# Rotation matrix by yaw

Tags: math, matrix, rotation, opengl-es-2.0, rotational-matrices

I want to set the yaw of a rotation matrix so an object points to a specific position using this code

```
Vector3 dist = transform().position() - mPlayerTarget;
transform().rotationZ(atan2(dist.x(), dist.y()));
```

This would produce the right results, except the rotation is inverse, so instead of following the target point it rotates away from it.

```
Vector3 dist = transform().position() - mPlayerTarget;
transform().rotationZ(-atan2(dist.x(), dist.y()));
```

(with -atan2) the object follows the target, but it's offset by a 90 degrees to the right. The rotationZ implementation looks like this:

```
float cz = cosf(rotation);
float sz = sinf(rotation);

matrix.mMatrix[0] = cz;
matrix.mMatrix[1] = sz;
matrix.mMatrix[2] = 0;

matrix.mMatrix[3] = -sz;
matrix.mMatrix[4] = cz;
matrix.mMatrix[5] = 0;

matrix.mMatrix[6] = 0;
matrix.mMatrix[7] = 0;
matrix.mMatrix[8] = 1;
```

I'm using iOS OpenGL ES 2.0. Something seems fundamentally wrong here, the first version should be the one producing the right results? All the other transformations seem to work properly. What could go wrong here? I don't know where to look for errors...

Comment: Just a couple of hunches: atan2 is usually defined as atan2(y, x), whereas you have it the other way around. Another strange thing may come from the direction of your dist vector - it goes from the target towards the transform position. You might try reversing it.

Comment: Both these things fixed it, thanks!

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll put it up as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is atan2 - it is usually defined as atan2(y, x), whereas you have it the other way around.

Another source of issues might be the direction of your dist vector - it goes from the target towards the transform position. Try reversing it.